# what is the sum of the numbers form -100 to 98

Tags: contest-math

Hello I need help with a contest question that I am not very sure about thanks.

What is the sum of the numbers from negative one hundred and ninety eight?

Comment: $(-100)+(-99)$, I would dare to say.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I second that.

Comment: I know that -199 is the ans but using the formula of a series Sn=n(a1+a2)/2 the ans I get is -198

Comment: not following sry is there a reason why I get -198 using the formula for a series?

Comment: You have 199 sequence members not 198.

Comment: I understand so 0 is a digit

Answer (score 2):

So you have the following sequence $-100, -99,-98,\ldots, 0,1,2,\ldots, 98.$

Your last term say $a_n=98$ which is equal to $$a_n=a+(n-1)d$$

$$98=-100+(n-1)\times 1$$ $$198=n-1$$ $$n=199$$

Now you have $a=-100, n=199, d=1$, use the formula you have mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach not involving any formulas

you want to sum $$-100,-99,-98,\cdots-2,-1,0,1,2,\cdots,97,98$$

As you can see $98$ cancels out with $-98$ similarly $97$ cancels out with $-97$
and similarly, everything cancels out till 0

In the end, you are left with -100,-99,0

Thus required sum is $$-100-99=-199$$